# Neo4j-Neoclipse Concurrent access issue

Tags: concurrency, neo4j, spring-data, neoclipse

I am creating a few nodes in neo4j using spring data, and then I am also accessing them via `findByPropertyValue(prop, val)`.

Everything works correctly when I am reading/writing to the embedded DB using spring data.

Now, as per the `Michael Hunger's book : Good Relationship`, I opened up `Neoclipse` in `read-only` mode connection to my currently active Neo4j connection in Java..

But, it somehow still says that Neo4j's kernel is actively used by some other program or something.

`Question 1 :`What am I doing wrong here?

Also, I have created a few nodes and persisted them. Whenever I restart the embedded neo4j db, I can view all my nodes when I do `findAll()`.

`Question 2 :`When I try to visualize all my nodes in `Neoclipse`(considering the db is accessible), I can only see `one single` node(which is empty), has `no properties` associated to it, whereas I have a `name` property defined.

I started my java app, persisted few nodes, traversed and got the output from in the java console. Now, I shutdown the application and started the `Neoclipse` IDE, connected to my DB and found that no nodes are present(Problem of Question 2).
After trying again(heads down), I go back to my Java app and ran my app, and surprisingly I found that I am getting a Lucene-file-corrupted error(`unrecognized file format`) error. I had no code changes, I did not delete anything, but still got this error.

`Question 3 :`Not sure what I am doing wrong. But since I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/v1ZDG1IKbtc) discussion on my bug(lucene/concurrent db access), I am willing to know if this is a `bug` or if this is due to any programatic error.(Does it have to do something with `Eclipse Juno`)

Any reply would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you are properly committing the transactions.
2. Data is not immediately flushed to the disk by Neo4j and hence you might not be viewing the nodes immediately in Neoclipse. I always restart the application that is using Neo4j in 
   embedded mode so that data is flushed to the disk and then open neoclipse.

Posting your code would help us to check for any issues.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Interestingly, if I do not create any relationship between the committed nodes, I do not see anything in Neoclipse. I was just committing a few nodes(but not `associating/relating` them). I ran this cypher query in `neoclipse` and found that it shows only when we create relation between them. :(
Code : `START sample=node(0)
WITH sample
CREATE(_1 { name:"name1" }),(_2 { name:"name2" }), sample-[:CONNECTED_TO]->_1, _1-[:CONNECTED_TO]->_2
`
This guy shows the results, but when I remove the CONNECTED_TO part, it probably creates the nodes, but doesnt visualize them.

Comment: Also, I am using `@Neo4jTransactional` instead of `@Transactional`, is that the way to go? I tried using normal spring `@Transactional` but it wasn't committing to the db. `@Neo4jTransactional` does commit properly. But I've never seen anyone using `@Neo4jTransactional`. Could you please comment on that? Thanks.

Comment: @Transactional will and should work. Post a different question with your code. Make a simple JUNIT.

Comment: Yea works :) Had a bug earlier which made me use @Neo. Thanks, pangea.

Comment: This certainly helped, but I have 1 more question. Is is possible to pls advice me how to go about.. doing a Same Entity Relationship.. For ex. Entity(class Person) relatesTo Entity(class Person).

Comment: CODE : 
`@NodeEntity
public class Person{
    @GraphId
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Indexed(indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT, indexName = "searchByPersonName")
    private String personName;

  @Fetch
  @RelatedTo(type = "CONNECTS_TO", direction = Direction.BOTH)
  private Set<ConnectedDevices> connectedPersons;
    
  public ConnectedPersons connectsTo(Device endPerson, String connectionProperty) {
     ConnectedPersons connectedPersons = new ConnectedPersons(this, endPerson, connectionProperty);
   this.connectedPersons.add(connectedPersons);
   return connectedPersons;
  }`

Comment: CODE: 
`@RelationshipEntity(type = "CONNECTED_TO")
public class ConnectedPersons{

 @GraphId
 private Long id;
 
 @StartNode
 private Device startPerson;
 @EndNode
 private Device endPerson;
 
 private String connectionProperty;
 
 public ConnectedPersons() {
  
 }
 
 public ConnectedPersons(Person startPerson, Person endPerson, String connectionProperty) {
  this.startPerson = startPerson;
  this.endPerson = endPerson;
  this.connectionProperty = connectionProperty;
 }`

Comment: I am trying to have a `Relationship` to the same class.. i.e. `Persons connected to the Person`.. When I invoke a Junit test : 
`Device one = new Device("One");
Device two = new Device("Two");
deviceService.save(one);
deviceService.save(two);
 
Iterable<Person> persons = personService.findAll();
 
for (Person person: persons) {
System.out.println("Person Name : "+person.getPersonName());
}
one.connectsTo(two, "Sample Connection");
template.save(one);`

I get Null pointer when I try to do `one.connectsTo(two, "Prop");

Please could you tell where am I going wrong?

Thanks and sorry for trouble.

Comment: @FirstBlood As you can see it is very hard to understand the code when you add as a comment. Please post a new question. I will take a look at that then.

Comment: Ohh :( alright I am accepting your answer.. pls take a look at the new question. thanks.

Comment: Link to the new question is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413242/neo4j-same-entity-relationship-persistence-issue

Comment: @FirstBlood answered your new question